# Javascript function not returning dictionary which it should be

Tags: javascript, function, async-await, nested

I currently have two javascript functions which both produce the desired result alone, however when together do not.

The first function is process results. All this does is log the result of calling another function, textToTime. The text to time function accepts a dictionary and returns another dictionary, with a string time converted to an integer time.

For example,

```
textToTime({A: "32 min", B: "1 hour 10 min" C: "2 hours 1 min"})
```

should return

`{A: 32, B: 70, C: 121}`

Here are the following functions:

```
async function processResults(options) {
    var bestOption = "";
    var display = false;
    options = await textToTime(options);
    console.log(options);
}
```

```
function textToTime(options) {
    for (var key in options) {
        let total = 0;
        let current = options[key];
        if (current == "n/a") {
            total = -1;
        }
        else {
            var num = "";
            for (let i = 0; i < current.length; i++) {
                if (isNumeric(current.charAt(i))) {
                    num += current.charAt(i);
                }
                else {
                    if (current.charAt(i) == "h") {
                        total += 60 * parseInt(num);
                        num = "";
                    } 
                    if (current.charAt(i) == "m") {
                        total += parseInt(num);
                        num = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        options[key] = total;
    }
    return options;
}
```

When I run `textToTime` alone, it always produces the correct output, however when I call it from inside `processResults`, it tends to return only part of the dictionary with integers and the rest still in the string format like: `{A: 32, B: "1 hour 10 min", C: "2 hours 1 min"}`

Any knowledge or support is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This code works just fine, please share "isNumeric" function implementation.

Comment: Also, You should use await for calling a synchronous function that is "textToTime".  
 change _options = await textToTime(options);_ to **options = textToTime(options);**

Comment: ```function isNumeric(str) {
    if (typeof str != "string") return false
    return !isNaN(str) && !isNaN(parseFloat(str))
}```

Answer (score 0):

in processResults function you have **options** argument , then you pass **options** to textToTime function and you assign the result to the **options** !!!!

this is not correct! change the last options to res or result or apiResult so that you avoid confusion! it also may result in unexpected behavior and cause errors

Comment: Why would assigning the return of `textToTime()` to `options` cause unexpected behavior?

Comment: I'm not talking about name of your function , I'm talking about options argument that textToTime function have! see , your function gets the argument options , and then your are assigning result of your api call to the options that was passed in to your function , this is a bad approach in your variables naming.

Comment: I was asking why that is a bad approach.

Comment: causing confusion for javascript and developer

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine just use `$.isNumeric()` method instead of `isNumeric()` becuase of this is not defined method.

Helpful Link:  `https://api.jquery.com/jquery.isnumeric/`

```js
async function processResults(options) {
    var bestOption = "";
    var display = false;
    options = await textToTime(options);
    console.log(options);
}

function textToTime(options) {
    for (var key in options) {
        let total = 0;
        let current = options[key];
        if (current == "n/a") {
            total = -1;
        }
        else {
            var num = "";
            for (let i = 0; i < current.length; i++) {
                if ($.isNumeric(current.charAt(i))) {
                    num += current.charAt(i);
                }
                else {
                    if (current.charAt(i) == "h") {
                        total += 60 * parseInt(num);
                        num = "";
                    }
                    if (current.charAt(i) == "m") {
                        total += parseInt(num);
                        num = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        options[key] = total;
    }
    return options;
}

processResults({ A: "32 min", B: "1 hour 10 min", C: "2 hours 1 min" })
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```